# Kdb+ keyed table syntax in tick.q

Tags: c, database, kdb, q

I was following this docs :
https://code.kx.com/q/wp/capi/#publishing-to-a-kdb-tickerplant

In the sym.q :
trade:([]time:`timespan$();[sym:`symbol$()];price:`float$();size:`long$())

Now what I want is to use keyed table that is why above schema is following keyed table syntax.
But the problem is all the tickerplant schema should be starting with time:timespan column and problem it was causing is that when i typed `type trade` its returning 98h and not 99h (which is the type number for keyed table).

So in the r.q :

```
/q tick/r.q [host]:port[:usr:pwd] [host]:port[:usr:pwd]
/2008.09.09 .k ->.q

if[not "w"=first string .z.o;system "sleep 1"];

upd:upsert

/ get the ticker plant and history ports, defaults are 5010,5012
.u.x:.z.x,(count .z.x)_(":5010";":5012");

/ end of day: save, clear, hdb reload
.u.end:{t:tables`.;t@:where `g=attr each t@\:`sym;.Q.hdpf[`$":",.u.x 1;`:.;x;`sym];@[;`sym;`g#] each t;};

/ init schema and sync up from log file;cd to hdb(so client save can run)
.u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;if[null first y;:()];-11!y;system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y};
/ HARDCODE \cd if other than logdir/db

/ connect to ticker plant for (schema;(logcount;log))
.u.rep .(hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`;`];`.u `i`L)";
```

I have upsert, but since its not really keyed table its causing to insert duplicate entries again and again instead of updating the same row of unique key.

Comment: Why did you tag it with C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table definition isn't valid. You seem to have

```
trade:([]time:`timespan$();[sym:`symbol$()];price:`float$();size:`long$())
```

which I think means that you want the table to be keyed by symbol. In that case the table definition should be:

```
trade:([sym:`symbol$()]time:`timespan$();price:`float$();size:`long$())
```

But you probably don't want to have the table keyed within the tickerplant schema, only the rdb should key it. That way you maintain a replayable log in the tickerplant, and you don't have to alter the tickerplant logic (the "timesym" check would need to be removed and the upd function would have to timestamp the data not as the first column).

So you should keep the trade schema unkeyed

```
trade:([]time:`timespan$();sym:`symbol$();price:`float$();size:`long$())
```

and you could change your replay function in the rdb to:

```
upd:insert; /initially set it to be insert so that the replay will work
.u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;if[null first y;:()];-11!y;`trade set select by sym from trade;`upd set (upsert);system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y};
```

Here I'm suggesting you initially set upd:insert so that the replay can work as normal (note - the tickerplant logs *lists* to log file, not tables, and upsert only works with tables). After the replay is complete then you can key your trade table and set upd to be upsert.

Final point to note is that the `upsert` will be slower than the default `upd:insert` on the subsequent messages.

Comment: Thankyou! But if I dont make the trade table keyed in the tickerplant schema, then when i publish the data to tickerplant it will be table without keys and it publishes the data to rdb where rdb will have the same schema too which results in unkeyed table and duplicate entries ? because some other services will be accessing rdb keyed tables

Comment: never mind! RDB during startup already calls that replay function and converted to keyed table, am i understanding correct ?

Comment: there seems to be problem for this while replaying : 
'type
  [3]  /home/naseef/q/l64/tick/r.q:20: .u.rep:
 if[null first y;:()];
 -11!y;
    ^
 system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y}

I am getting this error when exiting rdb and starting rdb process again

Comment: Try putting a break in your upd function to capture the attempted replay, then debug the type issue. ```upd:{.debug.x set x;.debug.y set y;break;x upsert y}```

Comment: Is this also because keyed tables cannot be splayed ? Should i look for another solution If i want replay mechanism for keyed table ??

Comment: Forget about splaying, solve your type issue first

Comment: Thanks! When i inserted data with above upd function you given, in the rdb process it prints this : 
`q)'.debug.x`

Comment: code :   
K singleRow = knk(3, ks((S) "ABC"), kf(50.0), kj(654));
  K result = k(wrapper1.handle(), ".u.upd", ks((S) "maman"), singleRow, (K)0);

Comment: when replaying : 
```
'.debug.x
  [4]  /home/naseef/q/l64/tick/r.q:6: upd:{.debug.x set x;.debug.y set y;break;x upsert y}
```

Comment: Apologies, my backticks disappeared in the formatting. It should be ```upd:{`.debug.x set x;`.debug.y set y;break;x upsert y}```

Comment: No need to apologise at all! 

while replaying the results : 
'break
  [4]  /home/naseef/q/l64/tick/r.q:6: upd:{`.debug.x set x;`.debug.y set y;break;x upsert y}


the arrow is actually pointing to the break just after this line : ``.debug.y set y`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256394/discussion-between-terrylynch-and-works).

Comment: I messaged there! thanks by the way

Answer (score 1):

@works Maybe not the answer you're looking for but if you are struggling to understand tick.q I created a blog explaining the content line by line. You can find it here https://www.defconq.tech/docs/tutorials/tick

Comment: thankyou so much! Also you can please help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77720813/getting-replay-error-for-keyed-tables-kdb
Its related to rdb

but damn your link is soo helpful! thankyou so much for that link

Comment: yes I replied to that one as well. I generally would avoid to defined keyed tables in the schema file. Keep everything unkeyed and process them on the Real-time subscriber as needed. Main reason is you cannot splay keyed tables

Comment: Here the real time subscriber is rdb too right ? i have some engines that query from the rdb for based on keys (python code).

Comment: yes the RTS is the RDB in this case. The question is, let's say you key by sym, what value do you store? All of them, just the last entry? If you just store the last entry you can simply create a last value cache `select by sym from table`. It really is use case dependent. Btw if you use `select by col from t` this will always return the last value for the specific by clause if you don't specify the columns you want to select. https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#9343-grouping-with-aggregation (last TIP here)